# how to apply 2 events(both mouse click or key pressed) for a button in javafx

Tags: javafx

I actually need to perform a button click event upon pressing key enter as well as when mouse click is done.

Please Help me with the syntax if possible.

Comment: Simply use the `onAction` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

if i got it right this example guides you:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;



    public class DoubleEvent extends Application{

        private Label label;
        private int counter;

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

            VBox root = new VBox(5);

            label = new Label("press enter or button");
            Button button = new Button("click me or press enter");

            button.setOnAction(event -> myActionMethod());

            root.getChildren().addAll(label, button);
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200));
            primaryStage.show();

            counter = 0;
        }

        private void myActionMethod() {
            counter++;
            label.setText("Event triggerd " + counter + " times");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Focus on ".setOnAction()".
Combine this with calling custom methods and the door is open for everything.

Comment: i've tried this too..but the event isn't getting triggered when enter key is pressed.